# Setting videoview size to be exactly 200dp

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-videoview

I'm setting the videoview in the onBindViewholder of my recyclerView but I want the height of the video to be 200dp. 
I tried using setLayoutParams() but it's not working or setting the video height in xml as well.
Please suggest me a way of how can I stretch or compress the video height in this condition.

Comment: so giving height 200dp don't work in xml?

Comment: no, the videoview set it's height according to it's aspect  ratio

Comment: Try to set it after you load the video.